# Is it possible to save Openstreets Map (leaflet) as an image

Tags: html5-canvas, extjs4.1, openstreetmap, leaflet

I am using leaflet with openstreetmaps to generate a map on Ext js panel.
As maps are coming as tiles in openstreet maps, I need to combine these tiles to create a single image in order to save as an image  .

Answer (score 1):

You can save a Leaflet Map as a PNG file by using [this resource](https://github.com/tegansnyder/Leaflet-Save-Map-to-PNG)

> Saving a Leaflet Map to a PNG Example using Javascript and PHP

Comment: Thanks man,I tried this demo but actually its showing some errors.

Comment: actually the url fired when clicking on save button they mentioned in the demo is not there.its showing 404 error. The url trying to fire is http://html2canvas.appspot.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fa.tile.cloudmade.com%2FBC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707%2F997%2F256%2F13%2F4095%2F2724.png&callback=html2canvas_3 . but even html2canvas.appspot.com is not there.

Comment: its because of - 
Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy.

Comment: In what part are you getting the Cross-origin? You can try the screenshoot part (html2canvas) on http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html without PHP stuff. Once you got the first part working, then you can set up PHP part at your convenience to avoid the Cross-origin.

Answer (score 1):

I do this using the so called **Tile Stitching** method (server side). Steps are:

- On the client side collect all the tile images in your document, for example using jQuery you could do:

  ```
  $('[class^="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"]')
  ```

That will give you an array with all the img elements of the tiles for your map.

- get the width and height, x and y, and the url of the images and put in a data structure of your liking
- send the data structure to a function on your server that will retrieve the urls and stitch the images together using the x,y,width,height attributes.

I got the idea from this article used with openlayers: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/TileStitchingPrinting. In the article you will find a working php example. Using the information above the javascript portion for Leaflet should not be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

http://www.yncoder.com/save-leaflet-map-as-image/

```
var images = container.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    images[i].src = images[i].src;
}

var canvas  = document.getElementById('dumb');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (typeof images[i] != 'undefined') {
        context.drawImage(images[i],
            images[i].style.left.slice(0, -2), // slice off 'px' from end of str
            images[i].style.top.slice(0, -2),
            images[i].clientWidth,
            images[i].clientHeight
        );
    }
}

window.open(canvas.toDataURL());
```